# Intercept all exceptions from a certain app in Django/DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For example a have a main app, let’s say for users handling and secondary app where I would create logs, models change history, statistics, ets.
Generally most of the CRUD activity in main app tigers CREATE operations in secondary app via signals to create logs and stuff.

What I want to achieve is to avoid exceptions being raised by secondary app from being propagated and shown to user via DRF response or make them ‘fail silently’ in a way, as , for instance, is user would update his account and history log subsequently created in secondary model would raise Integrity error – better just continue and do nothing rather then notify user about it.

There are to main types of exceptions - IntegrityError and ValidationError.

I could try to try/except all validation ones and maybe use custom exception handler to intercept Integrity errors if I know constraints names  but
a) I still can’t intercept them all as some of them are originated from Django source code
2) A lot of hardcode.

Question is – is it possible somehow to intercept all exceptions from a certain app and suppress them all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re very aware that suppressing all exceptions is bad practice in it’s own right, however, considering your situation perhaps you can try something like this `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False)` in your APIs